# searching through a list within lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to create a code that can append a file to a list, strip and split it, and find lines from `Payments.txt` that matches with the rule, which is find a customer that has a status of "A" AND still has outstanding money to pay. I can do the first two criteria's and can do the third one partially. I can find the customers that has amounts outstanding, but not the ones that has a status of "A". I have to use a list, not a dictionary by the way.

This is my code below:

```
myList = []
Status = "A"
myFile = open("Payments.txt")
record = myFile.readlines()
for line in record:
    myList.append(line.strip().split(','))
myFile.close()
for z in record:
    details = [[x for x in myList if x[0] == Status], [x for x in myList if x[2] > x[4]]]  #This is were I am having trouble
    if details:
        print(details)
        break
```

And this is the result:

`[[], [['E1234', '12/09/14', '440', 'A', '0'], ['E3431', '10/01/12', '320', 'N', '120'], ['E5322', '05/04/02', '503', 'A', '320'], ['E9422', '26/11/16', '124', 'N', '0']]]`

Why am I getting an empty list at the start of the result? There isn't a blank line in `Payments.txt`.

The list structure is as follows:

```
['Customer number', 'Date when they joined', 'Total amount', 'Status', 'Amount paid']
```

Comment: Why do you have to use a list? Also it's a little difficult to tell what you're actually asking here. Can you provide a better sample input and the desired output?

Comment: It is part of the rules to use a list. I want the program to select lists from `myList` that fit into having the status of "A" and not having paid all the money that is meant to be paid. So from the results above, I want the code to return the list starting with `E1234` and `E5322` as both have a status of "A" and the amount paid is less than the total amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[x for x in myList if len(x) == 5 and x[3] == Status and x[2]>x[4]]
```

In `len(x) == 5`, 5 represents the length of the normal list structure. It preferable to replace it by a variable.

Comment: I think you mean `myList` insead of `record`. With `record`, nothing came up, but with `myList`, it worked! Thanks for the input!

Comment: Ouups sorry, you're right it's myList and not record :) ! You're welcome ;) !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
details = [[x for x in myList if x[0] == Status and x[2] > x[4]]
```

I think the reason why you're getting one is because you check either A or the greater than.

Comment: It didn't return anything